# failed to create AWS R3.2xlarge instance via Jclouds

Tags: amazon-web-services, jclouds

I try to create a new type instance on AWS for high memory-consumption computing, r3.2xlarge
however, it failed all the time :

Java::JavaUtil::NoSuchElementException: hardwareId(r3.2xlarge) not found
    org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.throwNoSuchElementExceptionAfterLoggingHardwareIds(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:756)
    org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.findHardwareWithId(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:743)
    org.jclouds.compute.domain.internal.TemplateBuilderImpl.build(TemplateBuilderImpl.java:694)

So JClouds doesn't support this new instance type yet ?

My codes work fine with m1,m2,m3 instance.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is still not supported.
The AWS API does not provide a way to retrieve the available instance sizes. All known sizes are hardcoded in jclouds, and every time they release a new one we have to add it. Would you mind opening an issue and post it back so we can track it?
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS